# Not able to run shell script using ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have a script which starts a java application

as below nameof the file startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ./app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev > startup.log & 
echo $! > ./app.pid
```

and it has permission as

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root        41 Oct 22 20:58 shutdown.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root       144 Oct 22 20:58 startup.sh
```

if i run the same script in machine i will run

But if i run from other machine in (jenkins job)

```
ssh root@remotemachine.com '/opt/app/startup.sh'
```

it not running, or not starting the jar

UPDATE 1

Yes the other commands are running

```
ssh root@remotemachine.com 'cd /home; ls -la'   
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 27  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 May  2 12:06 ..
```

Update 2
Set PATH and JAVA_HOME

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64

# echo $PATH
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

Comment: Is the `./app.jar` present in the remote machine at the path `/opt/app/`?

Comment: yes.. if run same script in the remotemachine.com its running

Comment: could you explain "is not running" ? do `ssh ls` or `ssh hostname` give ls or hostname of remote host ?

Comment: updated the question.. yes ls cmd is running

Comment: it show total 8 but not showing the other than . and .. folders? is some issue which ssh key? means auth?

Comment: thanks for update, it looks like `java` is not in your `$PATH`.

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/latest it has.. if not it will not start if i run in the from system.

Comment: `$JAVA_HOME` and/or `$PATH` is probably not set properly due to nat ever starting an interactive shell. Set it in the script itself.

Comment: added PATH and JAVA_HOME also

Comment: Note that to see what these values are when you connect through `ssh`, you should be using `ssh root@remotemachine.com 'echo $PATH; echo $JAVA_HOME'`.  Testing in an interactive shell will not give you the same environment as when you run a command through `ssh`.  If you need `$PATH` and `$JAVA_HOME` to be particular values for the script to work, then set these variables to those value _in the script_.

Comment: here is the output ssh root@remotemachine.com 'echo $PATH; echo $JAVA_HOME'
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh root@remotemachine.com '/opt/app/startup.sh'
...
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ./app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev > startup.log & 
echo $! > ./app.pid
```

When you run `startup.sh` in this fashion, the working directory for the process (on the remote system) is going to be the root user's home directory. that directory is probably "/" or "/root" or something like that. Your script doesn't contain any `cd` commands, so it's going to try to access `app.jar`, `startup.log`, and `app.pid` in root's home directory. There probably is no file named `app.jar` in root's home directory, so the java command fails to do anything.

If you want to access all of these files in `/opt/app`, then you should change to that directory on the remote system:

```
ssh root@remotemachine.com 'cd /opt/app && /opt/app/startup.sh'
```

Alternately, you could change to the correct directory inside the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/app || exit 1
java -jar ./app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev > startup.log & 
echo $! > ./app.pid
```

Comment: Thanks thats working.. added cd command in the script file